# CountryDropdown look to be made similar to default Select style

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, html-select

- **Background**

If you see below image, the first two drop downs have similar look, but 3rd one has a different look.

[image]

1. List item

In first two I used CountryDropdown and RegionDropdown ( react-country-region-selector ). But for the 3rd one, I used react-select.

- **Issue**

Look of CountryDropdown and RegionDropdown are not matching with the 3rd Select component.

- **Expectation**

CountryDropdown and RegionDropdown should have same style ( Look and feel ) as of the 3rd Select component.

Please direct me to solve this problem.

```html
<Row>
  <div className="input-group" style={textboxDivStyle}>
    <CountryDropdown style={{ width: "300px" }}
      value={country}
      onChange={(val) => changeCountry(val)} />
  </div>
</Row>
<Row>
  <div className="input-group" style={textboxDivStyle}>
    <RegionDropdown style={{ width: "300px" }}
      country={country}
      value={state}
      onChange={(val) => selectState(val)} />
  </div>
</Row>
<Row>
  <div className="input-group" style={textboxDivStyle}>
    <div style={{ width: "300px" }}>
      <Select menuPlacement="auto" menuPosition="fixed" options={districts} value={district} onChange={changeDistrict} />
    </div>
  </div>
</Row>
```

Comment: Please make a formatting effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two libraries don't really seem compatible with each other. The `CountryDropdown` and `RegionDropdown` are an unstyled select components with the data built-in, and the `Select` is a fully styled select component that unfortunately does not work as a wrapper from what I can tell.  You have a few options here... Simplest being just to add styling directly to the Dropdown components and make it look as similar to the Select as possible. Otherwise, it might make sense to look for a different library OR you could get the data directly from this repo https://github.com/country-regions/country-region-data and pass as props into `Select`, which would probably allow you to achieve exactly what you want to but would also be the most time consuming.